# Advance calculator for finding the mode of a set of numbers

Tags: c, calculator

I am currently working on a project for school in which I need to program a calculator to determine the mode of a set of numbers. The parameters are the numbers have to be between 1 and 30. Have to check whether the user inserts a number within that range and that the number must be validated as an integer. I have most of it done except my main issues are the for loop in inputing the numbers and validating them and making sure my mode function works. Any suggestions in fixing the issue with the loop? Also I must use a mode function in order to calculate the mode does the one I'm using work well or is there a better way in going about it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int mode(int *num, int size);

int main(int n, char **p) {
    int modearray[], size, i;

    printf("What is the size of the Array?");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    for (i=0; i<modearray[size]; i++) {
        printf("Enter an integer value (1 to 30): ");
        scanf("%d", modearray[i]);

        if (modearray[i] < 1 || modearray[i] > 30) {
            printf("Please enter a value within the range");
            scanf("%d", modearray[i])
        }

        else if (sscanf(p[i], "%i", &a[i]) != 1) {
            printf("ERROR\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
}



//used the mode function code frome http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/43713-   pointers-and-modefunction/
int mode(int *num, int size) {
    int currentnum = (*num);
    int count = 0;
    int modenum = -1;
    int modecount = 1;

    for (int x=0; x<size; x++) {
        if (currentnum==(*num + x)) count ++;
        else {
           if(count > modecount) {
               modenum = currentnum;
               // modecount = count; 
               x--;
           }
           currentnum=*(num + x);
           count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u specify what exactlly the problem ?

Comment: Ok I guess I see it.

modeArray[] 
is not allocated and you trying to access it , you should first run modeArray = malloc(size * sizeof(int)); //not sure about malloc syntax I am on iPhone .

Comment: Please explain what you mean by mode? is it the type of operation you want to perform? (i.e. multiply, divide, add, subtract) or is it simply finding the number within the group with the highest number of occurances? (i.e. for  `1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7`, the mode would be 3)

Comment: Finding a number in a group with the highest number of occurrences. The main issue now is the line in the for loop in the main function always returns the PrintF("ERROR") message after the sscanf check even if the number I enter is an integer.

Comment: @JohnD'Amore - Look at my _latest_ post. I put it in awhile ago. It ran perfectly for me using ANSI C compiler on a Win 7 64 bit PC...

Comment: @JohnD'Amore - just curious, did the posts answer your questions?

Answer (score 2):

***As Charlie and user2533527 have already indicated***, there are errors in the OP code, and they have offered suggestions regarding those errors.  There are a few others that I have noted in my edit of your original code below, that without addressing, the code did not build and/or run.  So, if you are interested, look at the inline comments at the bottom of this post to see some corrections to your original code.

***This answer is focused on validation of input***, per your stated objective  (  *Have to check whether the user inserts a number within that range and that the number must be validated as an integer* ) Specifically it appears you need to verify that the numbers input fall within a range, *AND* that they all be an integers.

***If you move*** all of the validation steps into one function, such as:

```
int ValidateInput(char *num)
{
    if(strstr(num, ".")!=NULL) return FLOAT;
    if (atoi(num) < 1) return SMALL;
    if (atoi(num) > 30) return LARGE;
    return VALID;
}
```

then the main user input loop can be easily executed to include specific errors, if any, or continue with data collection by using a `switch()` statement, such as:

```
status = ValidateInput(number);
switch(status)  {
    case VALID:
        modearray[i] = atoi(number);
        printf("Enter an integer value %d: (1 to 30): ", i+2);

        break;
    case FLOAT:
        printf("float detected, enter an integer");
        i--;//try again
        break;
    case SMALL:
        printf("value too small, enter value from 1 to 30");
        i--;//try again
        break;
    case LARGE:
        printf("value too large, enter value from 1 to 30");
        i--;//try again
        break;
    default:
        //do something else here
        break;
}
```

Altogether, this approach does not use the mode function, rather replaces it with `ValidateInput()` which ensures only numbers that are integers, and within the stated range are included in the `modearray` varible.

***EDIT*** to include ***searching for mode*** (highest occurring number within group)

My approach will do three things to get ***mode***
***sort the array***,
***walk through the sorted array*** tracking count of the matches along the way.
***keep the highest string of matches***.

To do this, I will use `qsort()` and looping in the `mode()` function.

```
int mode(int *num, int size) {
    int count = 0;
    int countKeep=0;
    int modenum = -1;

    qsort(num, size, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
    //now we have size in ascending order, get count of most occuring
    for (int x=1; x<size; x++) 
    {
        if(num[x-1] == num[x]) 
        {
            count++; 
            if(count > countKeep)
            {
                countKeep = count;
                modenum=num[x];
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return modenum;
}
```

***Here*** is the complete code for my approach: (This code will capture the mode of a string of numbers with only one mode.  You can modify the looping to determine if the string is multi-modal, or having two equally occuring numbers)

```
#include <ansi_c.h> //malloc
//#include <stdio.h>//I did not need these others, you might
//#include <string.h>
//#include <math.h>  
int ValidateInput(char *num);
int mode(int *num, int size);
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b);

enum  {
    VALID,
    FLOAT,
    SMALL,
    LARGE
};

int main(int n, char **p)
{
    int *modearray, size, i;  
    int *a; 
    char number[10];
    int status=-1;
    int modeOfArray;

    printf("What is the size of the Array?");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    modearray = malloc(size*sizeof(int));
    a = malloc(size);

    printf("Enter an integer value 1: (1 to 30): ");
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) 
    {
        scanf("%s", number); 

        //Validate Number:
        status = ValidateInput(number);
        switch(status)  {
            case VALID:
                modearray[i] = atoi(number);
                printf("Enter an integer value %d: (1 to 30): ", i+2);

                break;
            case FLOAT:
                printf("float detected, enter an integer");
                i--;//try again
                break;
            case SMALL:
                printf("value too small, enter value from 1 to 30");
                i--;//try again
                break;
            case LARGE:
                printf("value too large, enter value from 1 to 30");
                i--;//try again
                break;
            default:
                //do something else here
                break;
        }
    }
    modeOfArray = mode(modearray, size);
    getchar();//to view printf before execution exits
}
int ValidateInput(char *num)
{
    if(strstr(num, ".")!=NULL) return FLOAT;
    if (atoi(num) < 1) return SMALL;
    if (atoi(num) > 30) return LARGE;
    return VALID;
}


int mode(int *num, int size) {
    int count = 0;
    int countKeep=0;
    int modenum = -1;

    qsort(num, size, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);
    //now we have size in ascending order, get count of most occuring
    for (int x=1; x<size; x++) 
    {
        if(num[x-1] == num[x]) 
        {
            count++; 
            if(count > countKeep)
            {
                countKeep = count;
                modenum=num[x];
            }
            else
            {
                count = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    return modenum;
}

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

Comment: This method works however my professor specified that we must either use/and or create a mode function. I edited my question at the top to be a little more specific I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the question is about crashing after the scanf in to array:

```
int main(int n, char **p) {
    int *modearray, size, i;

    printf("What is the size of the Array?");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    modearray = malloc(size * sizeof(int)); //imo size of int is 4 so u can replace with

    for (i=0; i<modearray[size]; i++) {
        printf("Enter an integer value (1 to 30): ");
        scanf("%d", modearray[i]);

        if (modearray[i] < 1 || modearray[i] > 30) {
            printf("Please enter a value within the range");
            scanf("%d", &modearray[i])
        }

        else if (sscanf(p[i], "%i", &a[i]) != 1) {
            printf("ERROR\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dont forget to free ur array in the end.